# Laravel Mass Assignment Using JSON

Tags: php, json, laravel, eloquent

These are my models:

Order:

```
class orders extends Model
{
protected $table = 'orders';
public function getItems()
{

    return $this->hasMany('App\order_items');
}


protected $fillable = [
   'subtotal','discount_amount','after_discount_price','mechanic_id','owned_cars_id','primary_id','promo_code_string',
    'order_status_id'
];

}
```

Order Items:

```
class order_items extends Model
{
protected $table = 'order_items';


protected $fillable = [
    'order_primary_id','primary_id','service_id','service_name','service_thumbnail','service_orignal_price','discount_amount',
    'after_discount_price','service_description','service_classification'
];
}
```

This is the JSON structure

```
{
  "orderID": null,
  "PromoId": 0,
  "subtotal": 2500,
  "discount": 12,
  "discountPrice": 3500,
  "mechanic_id": null,
  "ownedcarId": 1,
  "ownedCarServerId": 0,
  "order_status_id": 1,
  "order_items": [
    {
      "order_item_server_id": null,
      "order_id": null,
      "order_primary_id": 1,
      "primary_id": 1,
      "service_id": 1,
      "service_name": "Car Wash",
      "service_thumbnail": "asd",
      "service_original_price": 2500,
      "discount_amount": 20,
      "after_discount_price": 20,
      "service_description": "description",
      "service_classification": 1,
      "service_sub_items":0 

    }
  ]
}
```

For a new order this code works fine:

```
$order = new order();
$order->user_id = 123;
$order->fill($request->all()); 
$order->save();
```

Is there any way i can use $request->all() to save the mass assignable data in the key "order items" directly? Or do i have to do it one by one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have extra fields in your request that aren't meant to be in your model. You can do:

```
$input = $request->only(['username', 'password']);
$input = $request->only('username', 'password');

$input = $request->except(['credit_card']);
$input = $request->except('credit_card');
```

Taken from "Retrieving A Portion Of The Input Data" from https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/requests

Comment: There is a better way to do it.  https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#mass-assignment-json-columns

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
foreach($request->order_items as $item){
   $orderItem = new OrderItem($item);
   $orderItem->save();
}
```